# Using Push in Ionic 2

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to implement Push Notifications into an Ionic 2 app using the [official documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/Push/).

I have included the `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin, but when I insert the code they give you (wrapped in a platform ready function), like so:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     var push = Push.init({
       android: {
           senderID: "12345679"
       },
       ios: {
           alert: "true",
           badge: true,
           sound: 'false'
       },
       windows: {}
    });

});
```

I just get the following error:

`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Push is not defined`

Is there something else I need to do or is it not yet possible to use Push inside an Ionic 2 app?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I just used PushNotification in the end as per the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push docs.

Comment: How did you achive push notification can you give some explaination or step by step process to do it

Answer (score 2):

You import Push from 'ionic-native'?

```
import {Push} from 'ionic-native';
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I found the answer pretty much perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For push notifications in Ionic 2 you first need to setup Ionic Cloud: There is a guide here: https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html

Then you need to setup push notifications: https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/

The docs you linked to appear to be out of date.